# Intuit IPP QBO - Get Purchase

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using the QBO .Net SDK v3.0 and I'm trying to get the last bit of data I need from purchases.

I can get all the data I need from the purchase, and most of what I need from the purchase line item. The thing is, I can't get the expense details (chart of account info). Here' s the XML response from the api explorer for a line item under a purchase. It shows what I need, essentially "Office Expense".

```
<Line>

    <Id>1</Id>

    <Amount>74.97</Amount>

    <DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</DetailType>

    <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>

      <AccountRef name="Office Expense">52</AccountRef>

      <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>

      <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>

    </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>

  </Line>
```

I can get the data **not** contained by the AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail section with something like the following code (edited for brevity):

```
    // getting list of purchases....
    string pQuery = string.Format("Select * FROM Purchase", startDate);
    IEnumerable<Purchase> purchases = purchaseQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery(pQuery).ToList();

    // then loop through each line item of each purchase using an iterator
    for (int lineItem = 0; lineItem < numLines; lineItem++)

    // then get some data...
    lineAmount = purchaseInfo.Line[lineItem].Amount.ToString();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You are not getting the AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail?

Comment: D you use Plus subscription or Essentials?

Comment: Using the SDK, I cannot find a way to get the account based expense details, which are set by the user in QBO to provide a way to classify each purchase (Office Expenses, Travel, etc...) I see the data I need when I use the API explorer, so I know it is available. The info I'm trying to extract in my example is <AccountRef name="Office Expense">52</AccountRef>. I need "52" and "Office Expense". I am using the QBO starter edition, though the ability is there to classify expenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching a sample code used for invoice..similarly you can write for Purchase-

```
foreach (Line invoiceLine in x.Line)
                {
                    itm = new LineItem();

                    if (invoiceLine.Amount != 0)
                    {
                        itm.Description = invoiceLine.Description;
                        itm.Description = String.IsNullOrEmpty(itm.Description) ? "n/a" : itm.Description;

if (invoiceLine.DetailType == LineDetailTypeEnum.AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail)
                        {
                            AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail itemLineDetail =
                                invoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject as AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail;

                            itm.Quantity = 1;
                            itm.UnitAmount = invoiceLine.Amount;
                            itm.AccountCode = itemLineDetail.AccountRef.Value;
                        }
```